# background image wouldn't show in jumbotron on Bootstrap Studio?

Tags: html, css

im new to this.
i want to make an image as a background to my text that will say Welcome, !
i'm not sure if i should use jumbotron for this or just an image with text over it?
anyway i went ahead with jumbotron and my image would not show up; i have downloaded the banner image in the images folder.
here are some codes, i couldn't see where i've gone wrong, please help?

Relevant css codes

```
<head>
    link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/BS5-Jumbotron-with-background-Image.css"/>
</head>

<body class="text-end">
    <div class="p-5 mb-4 round-3 position-relative">
        <div id="bgImage" style="background-image:url('img src=/images/homepage_banner.jpeg');">
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid py-5 style=" z-index:999999">
            <h1 class="display-5 text-start fw-bold"> Welcome, nic!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: `background-image:url('/images/homepage_banner.jpeg');` you will find into the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image?retiredLocale=it)

Comment: N.b. you miss a `<` before declaring the CSS

Answer (score 0):

### Add your link tag properly

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/BS5-Jumbotron-with-background-Image.css"/>
```

Comment: thanks! i must have left that out when typing. besides that typo, is there anything else i could do? because the problem still persists :(

Comment: refer this code -> https://codepen.io/rockytechtips/pen/NWvXGEm

Comment: thank you so much! have a nice day/night :)